# `grep -z -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba\xbe'` doesn't match `LUKS\xba\xbe...`

Tags: grep, binary-files

I don't understand (based on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643334):

```sh
% grep -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba\xbe' /dev/sde  ### does not match
% echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS' ### matches
0:LUKS
% echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -z -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS' ### matches
0:LUKS
% echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -z -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba' ### does not match
% echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -z -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba\xbe' ### does not match
```

Why doesn't grep match (as it obviously should), and what do I have to do to make it match?

I had tried those commands in Tails 4.18 and in openSUSE Leap 15.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: The `grep` command interprets its input using the current locale.**

As you showed, this does not match:

```
echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -z -a -b -P --only-match 'LUKS\xba'
```

What's more, even the `.`, which should match everything, does not match:

```
echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -z -a -b -P --only-match 'LUKS.'
```

However, if we set the locale for this session ...

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

And then try again, it works:

```
echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | grep -z -a -b -P --only-match 'LUKS\xba'
```

Your locale depends on how your system is configured. Type `locale` to see all of the locale information. On my system, the default locale is `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`, which I believe means that `grep` is expecting it's input to be UTF8, and the input `LUKS\xba\xbe...` (hex `4c 55 4b 53 ba be 2e 2e 2e`) is not a valid UTF8 sequence. See `LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, LANG` in the Grep man page, and also note that it says, "The period . matches any single character.  **It is unspecified whether it matches an encoding error.**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Actually the two systems I had tried were using different locale settings, but they had UTF-8 in common (which is quite usual these days). What still surprises me is that both, `echo` and `grep` should use the same locale, but still the two strings seem to be different.

Comment: As it seems `\xba\xbe` are two characters for `echo`, but not for `grep`, because `echo -e 'LUKS\xba\xbe...' | env LC_ALL=C grep -a -b -P --only-match 'LUKS\xba'` works, too.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The example in your comment above works exactly the same as `echo 'LUKSgh...' | grep -o 'LUKSg'`, i.e. `grep` matches a portion of the input string. The string `\xba\xbe` represents 2 bytes for `grep` also.

Comment: If `\xba\xbe` are two bytes in both cases, so what's the issue with non-matching then? I thought grep is trying to make a Unicode character from them (while `echo` does not).

Comment: In "UTF8 mode", `grep` receives an encoding error (because the sequence is not valid UTF8) and returns a non-match. In POSIX mode (using `env LC_ALL=C`), `grep` sees `\xba\xbe` as 2 bytes.